# UE3-UnrealScript throw: Error, Code space for [FunctionName] overflowed by 77 bytes

Tags: overflow, unrealscript

Code as follows

```
enum Type
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
    NewEnumValue,  // new value
}

var() array<class<Inventory>> ArrayClasses;

function Test()
{
    ArrayClasses[TypeValue] = class<Inventory>(..., class'Class');
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ArrayClasses[NewEnumValue] = class<Inventory>(..., class'Class'); 
} // throw error
```

Assign values to array by enumeration, now thown error:

```
Error, Code space for [FunctionName] overflowed by 77 bytes.
```

This enum count be exceed 500. When I add the '*NewEnumValue*' to TypeEnum, and assign value in *Test* Function, throw error in this line, What the happen?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. Please, edit your post with some typos (funciton, erroe...) better copy and paste that retype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
Too many lines of code in the method, More than 708 lines will throw this error.
But I don't know why :(